# Sending email after creating an entry in SailsJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

I am trying to send an email from Sails after creating a user but I don't know what callback to use and can't seem to find anything in the documentation.

I reckon there should be some function which can be attached to the model like so:

```
afterCreate: function(user) {
   // do stuff with email here
}
```

but that doesn't work for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Docs about the lifecycle callbacks available for models are [here](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-docs/blob/master/models.md#lifecycle-callbacks).  You'll want to define an `afterCreate` method in your User model.  For sending the email, use something like the `nodemailer` package.